# Pin 9 and 10 with different duty cycles

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, pwm, atmega328

I want to control the contrast and backlight of an HD44780 LCD display with two PWM signals. I would like to use `PB1` and `PB2` (`Pin 9` and `Pin 10`) for this. 
As far as my research goes, `timer1` is responsible for the two pins.
`OCR1A` and `OCR1B` are responsible for the pulse length.

With the code below I get a frequency of 7.823 kHz and a duty cycle of 88%. But it works only on `PB1`. `PB2` is still constant `0V`. I am using the AtmelStudio, therefore I don't have access to functions like `pinMode(10, Output)`

How can I have different duty cycles on pin 9 and 10?

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= (1 << DDB1) | (1 << DDB2);
    OCR1A = 900;
    OCR1B = 400;
    TCCR1A |= (1 << COM1A1);
    TCCR1A |= (1 << WGM11) | (1 << WGM10);
    TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & 0b11111000) | (1 << CS10);

}
```

Comment: You can't control the contrast with PWM unless you filter it properly to provide the correct voltage. Personally I use a digipot for contrast.

Comment: I want to use PB1 for backlight and PB2 for contrast. `analogWrite()` is not inside AtmelStudio.

Comment: Maybe you should use the Arduino IDE with your Arduino. Or copy and paste the Arduino source code into your project.

Comment: As far as I have been able to test it. It will work. I might add a circuit to filter it but that's down the line.

Comment: Without a filter you will get flicker as it switches rapidly between full contrast and zero contrast.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will add one once I get the source code working.

Comment: Start by examining the Arduino source code. That works, so why not use it as a basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying  a lot of things i got it working.
And even the contrast is working directly on the pwm signal.

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
void main(void){
    DDRB = 0x06;
    OCR1A = 200; //Duty cycle for PB1 ~80%
    OCR1B = 100; //Duty cycle for PB2 ~40%
    TCCR1A = 0; //Set TCCR1A to zero. We will configure it manually
    TCCR1A |= (1 << COM1A1) | (0 << COM1A0) | ( 0 << COM1B0) | (1 << COM1B1);
    TCCR1A |= (0 << WGM12) | (0 << WGM11) | (1 << WGM10); 
    TCCR1B = 0; //Set TCCR1B to zero. We will configure it manually
    TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (0 << CS11) | (1 << CS10);
    while(1){

    }
}
```